# Hibernate one to many always return column not found when get

Tags: java, hibernate, db2

I have two hibernate entities with bidirectional onetomany and manytoone relation,

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Company")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property="@id")
public class Company {
    private int companyid;
    private List<Employee> employees;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "companyid")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public int getCompanyid() {
        return companyid;
    }

    public void setCompanyid(int cid) {
        companyid = cid;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "company", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
        return employees;
    }

    public void getEmployees(List<DiscountEntity> discountEntityList) {
        this.employees = discountEntityList;
    }
}
```

And the employee entity has this

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
public class DiscountEntity {

private int employeeid

    @Id
    @Column(name = "EMPLOYEEID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public int getEmployeeid() {
        return employeeid;
    }

    public void setEmployeeid(int employeeid) {
        this.employeeid = employeeid;
    }

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(columnDefinition = "companyid", referencedColumnName = "companyid")
    public Company getCompany() {
        return company;
    }

    public void setCompany(Company discountAgreement) {
        this.company = discountAgreement;
    }

}
```

The problem is when I call company.getEmployee(), I just get the following error

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not initialize a collection: [Company.employees#1]
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadCollection(Loader.java:2026)
    at org.hibernate.loader.collection.CollectionLoader.initialize(CollectionLoader.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:587)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:1744)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:366)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:108)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.readSize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.collection.PersistentBag.size(PersistentBag.java:248)
    at se.softronic.appialec.module.agentprovision.AgentProvisionTest.testPrepare(AgentProvisionTest.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:211)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: [SQL0205] Column COMPANY_COMPANYID not in table EMPLOYEE
    at com.ibm.as400.access.JDError.throwSQLException(JDError.java:650)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.JDError.throwSQLException(JDError.java:621)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCStatement.commonPrepare(AS400JDBCStatement.java:1576)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCPreparedStatement.<init>(AS400JDBCPreparedStatement.java:193)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCConnection.prepareStatement(AS400JDBCConnection.java:2023)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCConnection.prepareStatement(AS400JDBCConnection.java:1822)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection.prepareStatement(NewProxyConnection.java:213)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy$TransactionAwareInvocationHandler.invoke(TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy.java:239)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at se.softronic.util.sql.DelegatingConnection.prepareStatement(DelegatingConnection.java:212)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getPreparedStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:534)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getPreparedStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:452)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareQueryStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1577)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:696)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:259)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadCollection(Loader.java:2019)
    ... 40 more
```

It seems hibernate try to add COMPANY before the column COMPANYID, and then complain about it does not exists, I have the table correctly setup and it just won't work.

Answer (score 0):

It should be ...

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Company")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property="@id")
public class Company {
    private int companyid;
    private List<Employee> employees;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "companyid")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public int getCompanyid() {
        return companyid;
    }

    public void setCompanyid(int cid) {
        companyid = cid;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "company", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
        return employees;
    }

    public void setEmployees(List<Employee> employees) {
        this.employees = employees;
    }
}
```